# Where do I put non-Ruby files in my gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, directory-structure, upstart

I want to put an Upstart config file in my Ruby gem. Here's my current best guess

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|

  # ...

  s.files = %w(
    lib/rt_watchdog.rb
    lib/upstart/rt_watchdog.conf
    bin/rt_watchdog
  )
end
```

In general, where do configuration files and other types of scripts go in a gem?

**Update**: I changed the path in my example from `Upstart/rt_watchdog.conf` to `lib/upstart/rt_watchdog.conf` as that's what I've decided to go with for now, but I still don't feel great about it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard place for upstart files, but it's certainly not in a directory starting with a capital letter! If you're going to go this route, call it the lowercase `upstart`. But more likely just call it `config`, or put it in an appropriate subdirectory under `lib`.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I did wind up going with `lib/upstart/rt_watchdog.conf` for now, but I still don't feel great about it. What's more, I can't find a way to have a gem install deploy files for me, like a post-install script.

Comment: My research has indicated that a post-install script is not the way to go. Instead, I want to include a bin like `mygem_config` similar to Passenger Phusion's `passenger-install-nginx-module`.

Comment: yeah you better add an executable which will install your upstart file, installing a gem should not touch anything on the user's system (except the gem folder of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses a config directory in the root of the app and Rails conventions are pretty well represented throughout the Ruby community.

Comment: I agree about Rails conventions. Thank you. Would you have a tip as to how I should organize under config? Like `config/upstart` and `config/cron.daily`? That's what I'm doing now.